# How to cast Tinyint(1) MySQL EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have tried to get EF core to scaffold a MySQL DB using DB first and Pomelo but can't run simple queries because of the tinyint(1) to bool cast failure issue. Tried using both of these connection strings for scaffolds:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=ip.address.here;Database=DBNameUsername=UnameHere;Password=PasswordHereTreatTinyAsBoolean=false;" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL -OutputDir Models -force`

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=ip.address.here;Database=DBNameUsername=UnameHere;Password=PasswordHereTreatTinyAsBoolean=true;" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL -OutputDir Models -force`

If anyone could point out what's wrong that'd be great

```
public static Customer GetCustomerById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();

            using (Context db = new Context())
            {
                customer = db.Customer.Single(c => c.CustomerId == id);
            }

            return customer;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            // always errors on cast conversion failure here
            Console.WriteLine("error: " + err);
            throw new Exception($"couldn't find the customer with CustomerId: {id}");
        }
    }
```

here is the scaffold-ed model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Scheduler.Data.Models
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Appointment = new HashSet<Appointment>();
        }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public sbyte Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }

        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So chagning the field to tinyint(3) did the trick to at least pass the assert method, but there should be a way to do this with tinyint(1). Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for tinyint(1) column in table we used bool property in model and managed it manually. It worked

Comment: That may be the case for you, but I was not able to reproduce. A cast error is thrown saying it cannot convert "System.Boolean to sbyte", can you show any examples of it working please?

Comment: @CoderLee - Why is your `Active` property defined as `sbyte` and not `bool`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That's the way EF core scaffolds it. I have tried changing it to bool or boolean but you end up with the same error regardless.

Comment: which code throws the error? What is the error? Any snapshot.